# MiKTeX: can't install glossaries. "mfirstuc.sty not found"

Tags: miktex, glossaries

I know, this question has already been asked but none of the solutions work for me.

I've put the packages `mfirstuc` and `glossaries` in my preamble but I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mfirstuc.sty' not found.
```

with the following log:

```
2015-10-20 08:20:10,051+0200 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-10-20 08:20:10,145+0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2015-10-20 08:20:10,145+0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
2015-10-20 08:20:10,145+0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-10-20 08:20:10,145+0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2016-02-15 13:05:40,197+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-02-15 13:05:40,307+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2016-02-15 13:05:40,307+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
2016-02-15 13:05:40,307+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2016-02-15 13:05:40,307+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2016-02-15 13:05:48,252+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-02-15 13:05:48,377+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2016-02-15 13:05:48,377+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
2016-02-15 13:05:48,377+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2016-02-15 13:05:48,377+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2016-02-15 13:06:16,491+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-02-15 13:06:16,600+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2016-02-15 13:06:16,600+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
2016-02-15 13:06:16,600+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2016-02-15 13:06:16,600+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2016-02-15 13:11:41,088+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - installing package mfirstuc triggered by tex\latex\mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty
2016-02-15 13:11:42,726+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2016-02-15 13:11:42,726+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2016-02-15 13:11:42,726+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2016-02-15 13:11:42,944+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: lightweight database digest: 7abf16f1cb7fe2f999f177e6ac03366f
2016-02-15 13:11:43,007+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to download 496460 bytes
2016-02-15 13:11:43,007+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to install 13 file(s) (1 package(s))
2016-02-15 13:11:43,007+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:11:43,350+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 496460 bytes, 1413.48 KB/Sec
2016-02-15 13:11:43,350+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: extracting files from mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:11:43,397+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

2016-02-15 13:11:43,397+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\be48a8a88e3570f31e8be8fd4a43a2fd.fndb
2016-02-15 13:11:43,397+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
2016-02-15 13:11:43,397+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 120
2016-02-15 13:13:16,534+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - installing package mfirstuc triggered by tex\latex\mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty
2016-02-15 13:13:16,612+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2016-02-15 13:13:16,612+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2016-02-15 13:13:16,612+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2016-02-15 13:13:16,784+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: lightweight database digest: 7abf16f1cb7fe2f999f177e6ac03366f
2016-02-15 13:13:16,830+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to download 496460 bytes
2016-02-15 13:13:16,830+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to install 13 file(s) (1 package(s))
2016-02-15 13:13:16,830+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:13:17,142+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 496460 bytes, 1553.92 KB/Sec
2016-02-15 13:13:17,158+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: extracting files from mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:13:17,205+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

2016-02-15 13:13:17,205+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\be48a8a88e3570f31e8be8fd4a43a2fd.fndb
2016-02-15 13:13:17,205+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winMemoryMappedFile.cpp
2016-02-15 13:13:17,205+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 120
2016-02-15 13:15:05,895+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2016-02-15 13:15:06,020+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2016-02-15 13:15:06,020+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe
2016-02-15 13:15:06,020+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2016-02-15 13:15:06,020+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2016-02-15 13:19:36,585+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - installing package mfirstuc triggered by tex\latex\mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty
2016-02-15 13:19:36,666+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2016-02-15 13:19:36,666+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2016-02-15 13:19:36,666+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2016-02-15 13:19:36,852+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: lightweight database digest: 7abf16f1cb7fe2f999f177e6ac03366f
2016-02-15 13:19:36,901+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to download 496460 bytes
2016-02-15 13:19:36,902+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to install 13 file(s) (1 package(s))
2016-02-15 13:19:36,902+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:19:37,205+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 496460 bytes, 1616.08 KB/Sec
2016-02-15 13:19:37,207+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: extracting files from mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:19:37,279+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

2016-02-15 13:19:37,279+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc/latex/mfirstuc
2016-02-15 13:19:37,279+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\win.cpp
2016-02-15 13:19:37,279+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 2664
2016-02-15 13:19:55,444+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - installing package mfirstuc triggered by tex\latex\mfirstuc\mfirstuc.sty
2016-02-15 13:19:55,521+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2016-02-15 13:19:55,521+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2016-02-15 13:19:55,521+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: package repository: http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2016-02-15 13:19:55,688+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: lightweight database digest: 7abf16f1cb7fe2f999f177e6ac03366f
2016-02-15 13:19:55,734+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to download 496460 bytes
2016-02-15 13:19:55,734+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: going to install 13 file(s) (1 package(s))
2016-02-15 13:19:55,735+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: downloading http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:19:56,021+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: 496460 bytes, 1707.13 KB/Sec
2016-02-15 13:19:56,023+0100 INFO  miktex-pdftex - mpm: extracting files from mfirstuc.tar.lzma...
2016-02-15 13:19:56,064+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

2016-02-15 13:19:56,064+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc/latex/mfirstuc
2016-02-15 13:19:56,065+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\win.cpp
2016-02-15 13:19:56,065+0100 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 2664
```

And here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{mfirstuc}  
\usepackage{glossaries}  
\begin{document}  
Are you working?  
\end{document}
```

which produces the same error.

I have already tried to install all packages I might've been missing, synchronizing, using `mfirsuc` instead of only `glossaries`,
 writing it at the end of the preamble because there might be a package that I need in order to be able to use glossaries, updating,...

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Install the package with the MikTeX package manager

Comment: @Herbert I did... All I can do is uninstall all of them and reinstall

Comment: `Windows API error 5: Access is denied.` normally means that something if blocking the installation folder. Close everything remotely miktex related (e.g. also pdf documentations in adobe reader or in the windows explorer preview).

Comment: @Ulrike 
I closed everything that could be remotely related. When I try to compile I still get the same error

Comment: @Ulrike I also tried to compile with latexmk which didn't help either

Comment: You can't solve an installation problem by using a more complicated compilation method. Shut down your computer, restart and try to install mfirstuc with the package manager (admin and/or user).

Comment: @Ulrike Ok, thanks for your help! I'll be hopefully back with good news

Comment: @Ulrike I'm back with the same problem :-(